# PreviewMouseDown Routing to Border/Textblock Instead of Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to access the text of a button when I click on it. All the buttons are created by a Data Template. The buttons are inside a `UniformGrid` which is inside an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="uniformControl">
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <UniformGrid MouseDown="Button_PreviewMouseDown">
           </UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Button Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
```

Then in my code behind (my `Operations` class that has the binding content isn't included):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    uniformControl.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Button_PreviewMouseDown);

    uniformControl.ItemsSource = Operations.operations;
}

private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedElement = e.OriginalSource;
    Debug.WriteLine(clickedElement);

    string keyword = (e.Source as Button).Content.ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine(keyword);
}
```

Although, instead of the `OriginalSource` being a button, it is either a `textblock` or a `border`. I'm assuming this is due to `textblock` and `border` being the specific part of the button being clicked, since `PreviewMouseDown` traces the path to the smallest child element from what I understand.

The line where I assign a value to `keyword` throws a `NullRefernceExcpetion` as well.

I've tried using `MouseDown` instead, but the method didn't even run when I tried that.

Any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Comment: "_I'm trying to access the text of a button when I click on it_" Why? That sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is the underlying/real problem you try to resolve with this approach?

Comment: @elgonzo I'm making a calculator and I want to run different methods depending on what each button says i.e. if someone presses the `+` then do...

Comment: I see, but why would you use an ItemsControl for the keypad of a calculator? I fear i still don't understand what your end goal is. Why not just lay out the buttons directly in some panel (Grid?) and use the button's Command+CommandParameter properties, or alternatively use the button's Click event (which you could tie to different handlers/operations for each button)?

Comment: @elgonzo I wanted to use a `UniformGrid` to make it easier to lay out the buttons, since they are all next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the `Button.Click` event as an attached event on your `UniformGrid`, e.g. like this:

```
<UniformGrid Button.Click="Button_Click">
</UniformGrid>
```

And then access the button using `OriginalSource`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedElement = e.OriginalSource;
    Debug.WriteLine(clickedElement);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one last quick question: in the console it shows up as `System.Windows.Controls.Button: +` for example. Would the easiest way to make it only show `+` be to just use `Substring`?

Comment: @NathanChan Your could read the content of the clicked button in the way you did already in your question, using `(clickedElement as Button).Content`.